# Possibility to use GCC "--enable-frame-pointer" for 64bit targets

Tags: c++, gcc

I'd like to ensure that a large set projects are build with the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` flag for easier debugging with tools like ebpf.

One way of course would be to modify the build scripts of each of these projects, but that is a lot of work.

I've come across the possibility to configure gcc with `--enable-frame-pointer` which restores the old default from the early gcc4.x days of using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

I've built gcc from source like that and confirmed:

```
❯ ./bin/gcc -m32 -O3 -Q --help=optimizers | grep omit
 -fomit-frame-pointer [disabled]
❯ ./bin/gcc -m64 -O3 -Q --help=optimizers | grep omit
 -fomit-frame-pointer [enabled]
```

Is anyone aware of a possibility to extend the effect of `--enable-frame-pointer` to the 64bit targets?

Comment: sooo wouldn't `export CC="gcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer"` work?

Comment: It's not quite the same, as it relies on every used buildtool respecting this env variable. Of course, I could create a shell script to wrap gcc and put that in my path to achieve something similar and a bit more robust.  But I was more interested if this options was somehow also available for 64bit targets. Would just be easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using an older version of GCC because support of this flag on x64 has been enabled some time ago (see e.g. [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/fd661a34e53dd2b20ae5309b78960c171ff9a720) commit).

Comment: This is amazing! I was indeed still on 9.3.0.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but I've tried this on 10.2.0 and can see in the log files that USE_IX86_FRAME_POINTER gets set to 1, but if I then check the same commands as above, both return "enabled" ...

Comment: accepting as an answer again as I think the reporting of GCC has a bug, but the option in fact works as intended. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98783

Comment: @hassec +1 for taking time to report the bug! I wish all overflowers acted like that...